# Lawful interception: How-To identify a Private Relay user?

Tags: icloud, security, privacy, icloud-plus

In Germany there is the [NetzDG](https://wikiless.org/wiki/Network_Enforcement_Act?lang=en), if you post "hate" or criticize a decision maker harshly, you will be punished.

How do you identify a user who (exclusively) uses Private Relay?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [official paper by Apple](https://www.apple.com/privacy/docs/iCloud_Private_Relay_Overview_Dec2021.PDF) on how private relay works. There is a section about IP addresses and how it is routed.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you should not try to identify such a user beyond what is immediately available to you.

If you're reporting a crime to the police, the police handles the investigation and is responsible for identifying the user.

If you're filing a complaint with a service provider, social media platform, or similar, that company is responsible for identifying the user in their systems.

I don't know if you're asking as private person or related to your work. If this is a business, you might be yourself be breaking the law trying to identify users (for example the GDPR regulation).